# How to use Monaco Editor in WPF (Visual Studio 2019)?

Tags: c#, wpf, roblox, monaco-editor

I am currently making a Roblox exploit with WPF in Visual Studio 2019. I have coded most of the UI and the .DLL for the exploit, but I just need Monaco editor to finish it.

I tried looking at the Synapse X source for Monaco, but when I try and use Monaco the same way as Synapse X, I get an error. The error I get is "'require' is not defined (22)", but I don't know how to fix it.

Does anybody know another way that I could use Monaco in my WPF exploit without getting any errors?

Comment: Do you know you have a debug mode (versus release) ? Starting from there, you'll have some code to share, and then we'll be able to start discussing.

Comment: @Soleil Debug Mode Versus Release, what do you mean?

Comment: You can build a debug binary or a release binary; if you build a debug binary (you work in debug mode), you'll be able to debug your error, by stopping (automatically) where is occurs and check the variables, context etc. That what you can do. If you don't understand the reasons, you'll be able to post details here. So far your OP does not allow anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a webbrowser user control, and then configure it to host Monaco.